# Map Search within City Boundaries

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I am using `Google Places API` to search for Restaurants in a given area.

How do I to define the given area? e.g. I want to search in the district of Mumbai, Maharashtra. Now this is approx. 5000 sq. km and there is no way that I will get all the results from Google in one go.

So for doing incremental searching the solution is to do incremental searches by increasing the lat and long values from a given start point and keep on searching.

Sample Code -

```
lat_NW = 53.4017872352
lng_NW = 5.954233125
lat_SE = 51.9766032969
lng_SE = 10.032130575
lat_curr = lat_NW
lng_curr = lng_NW
total_calls = 0

lat_incr = -.29
lng_incr = .29

while lng_curr<lng_SE:
    lng_curr = lng_NW
        while lat_curr > lng_SE:
        curr_location = str(lat_curr) + "," + str(lng_curr)
         print curr_location
         url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=' + curr_location + '&sensor=false&key=' + GOOGLE_API_KEY + '&radius=20000&types=restaurant&name=mcdonalds'
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            result = response.read()
            d = simplejson.loads(result)
            print d
            lng_curr += lng_incr
        lat_curr += lat_incr
```

PS (I got this sample code at https://stackoverflow.com/ itself.)

Question - But the problem with this is that is assumes the area to be rectangular. Is there a way that we can

1. Identify the Lat, Long Boundaries of a city - e.g. Boston, MA from Google Maps itself? Obviously this will be polygon with a range of values and not just 4 points of a rectangle
2. If yes on the above, then the search can be made incrementally from the center point of the polygon using the a fix increment unto the max radius from the center and then pull all the information...

I looked at Google Documentation for [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngBounds) class and unfortunately (as I understood it), it talk about NE and SW corners resulting in a rectangle.

I searched for this on other posts on this forum and what I got is -

```
http://www.maptechnica.com/us-city-area-map/city/Boston/state/MA/cityid/2507000
City:   Boston, Massachusetts
Latitude/Longitude: 42.31435000000000, -70.96997850000000
Lat/Lon Northwest:  42.40082000000000, -71.19115500000000
Lat/Lon Southeast:  42.22788000000000, -70.74880200000000 
----   Rectangle Again
```

Seems that for now there is no open source database for cities and their polygonal boundaries.

Thanks for the help.
Manish